# Called object 'time' is not a function

Tags: c, time, stdio

I am using a very simple one line code to get the current time in C on ubuntu, but it is giving me the following error:
`Called object 'time' is not a function`

The code is:
`int currentTime = (unsigned int)time(NULL);`

This error makes no sense at all, what is the possible reason for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not being able to see your actual code makes it difficult but, first up, you need to ensure you have included `time.h` so that the function is declared.

Second, you need to ensure that there is no *other* thing in your code somewhere called `time`.

For example, this code works fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(){
    int currentTime = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    printf("%u\n", currentTime);
    return 0;
}
```

Whereas *this* code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int time;

int main(){
    int currentTime = (unsigned int)time(NULL);
    printf("%u\n", currentTime);
    return 0;
}
```

produces:

```
testprog.c: In function ‘main’:
testprog.c:5:38: error: called object ‘time’ is not a function
```

on my Debian box, which is *like* Ubuntu, only better :-)